# Can a Vertical PDU be mounted in an enclosed rack?

Tags: electrical-power, physical-environment, rack, rackmount

I purchased an enclosed 12U rack as well as Vertical (0U) PDU, but can't figure out how to mount it in the rack vertically.

I assume I need to mount it on the side posts of the enclosure, since, if I mount it on the front posts, it blocks all the units.  But, if I mount it on the side vertically, it sticks out of the enclosure.  The only way I can get it on the side is if take off the side panels and let it stick out.

- Do some enclosed racks not support Vertical PDUs? This is a Startech 12U.  I'd be happy to purchase another one, but the specs on enclosures don't seem to indicate whether they support Veritcal PDUs.
- Is there a better way to mount it?

I am new to using racks, so I appreciate answers that explain from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Many rack accessories (PDUs, cable management add-ons, etc.) are proprietary designs that only work with racks that are designed to hold them. Other than the standard spacing of the rack rails themselves ([EIA/ECA-310-E compliance](https://www.server-racks.com/eia-310.html)), you should typically expect mounting options to be wildly different between different racks.

Yes, some racks do not have space for a vertical PDU, and even if your rack does have space it may only fit certain models with specific mounting holes. ([The product images here](https://www.racksolutions.com/vertical-rackmount-powerstrips.html) give a good example of proprietary mounting solutions - though this specific product would not fit in your rack.)

Without seeing the manuals and/or spec sheets of your specific rack and PDU, I don't think we can give you specific ideas about mounting it.

If you want a solution that "just works", you need to buy a PDU that explicitly says it is compatible with your rack, most likely by buying the rack and the PDU from the same company. The sales people at most rack companies would probably be happy to help you find what you need.